# Use VBA with PS4 Remote Play?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA so that my computer hits "enter" every couple of seconds. The program works. However, I want to use this on my PS4 Remote Play and it's not working.

```
Sub dmv()
    waitTime (5000)
    For i = 1 To 6000
    Call SendKeys("{ENTER}")
    waitTime (2000)
    Next i
    
    End Sub
    
    Function waitTime(ByVal milliSeconds As Double)
    Application.Wait (Now() + milliSeconds / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000)
    
    End Function
```

Comment: what does "not working" mean?  You're getting an error, you're getting no results, you're getting unexpected results.  What application has focus when you send keys?

Comment: Hello,
What I mean by "not working" is that I'm getting no results when I open up the PS4 Remote Play application, but it works on my web browser and anywhere outside of that. I added the 5 second delay so that after I execute my program, I can pop out my PS4 Remote Play application and focus it. I hope this clarifies!

Comment: does it work if you manually press the "{ENTER}" key?  Also I think that {ENTER} is the code for the numeric keypad enter and not the 'normal' enter key, which is {~}.  There may be a difference in PS4 Remote Play.

Comment: Yes. It works when I manually hit enter on both the numpad and the normal. I tried changing it to ~ and it still doesn't work.